# ordering two columns ascending php mysql sequencing

Tags: php, mysql

Does MySQL can sort two columns sequentially? Please see my example query

```
<?php
 $qResults  =  mysql_query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablename ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2");

//The initial data is these

Column 1       Column 2
   7              24
   18              3
   2              25
   9              23
   17              8 
   1              15
   10             19
   20              4
   11              6
   16              5

//I want to sort it by this.
Column 1       Column 2
   1              15
   2              25
   18             3
   20             4
   16             5
   11             6
   7              24
   17             8
   9              23
   10             19

?><br>
```

Sorting two columns order by ascending. It this possible in the mysql query?

Comment: your query seems ok. can you provide your error.

Comment: it is not a mix of data this is the flow of my program. sometimes it goes to the column1 sometimes on column2 @MostyMostacho

Comment: Yes, sorry, just saw Illia's answer and then I saw what you were doing and his solution seems to be right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM torder
order by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this @llya. It works great but have a minor issues when i applied a where condition it displays all the results. Example WHERE column1 = 1 it displays two results.

Comment: @Shudmeyer put your full query, because I cannot reproduce this problem

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tablename WHERE column1 = 1
order by least(column1, column2), greatest(column1, column2). it must display only one result but it displays 2

Comment: @Shudmeyer if you have two rows from this query - this mean you really have two rows in table where column1 = 1, either remove wrong rows, or if both rows have same column2 - use `distinct`

Comment: yes it shows multiple data on column1 but not on column2. example 1  15, 1 20, its shows only 1   15 only with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$qResults  =  mysql_query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablename ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC");
```

It will sort column1 and then on column2 within column1

Comment: This doesn't result in the order the OP is looking for. You should read the question again.

Comment: This is the default behavior of mysql, To get both fields sorted you have to use array_sort functions over the sql result.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by array_sort nor the default behaviour of MySQL. But this answer just doesn't answer the question (regardless of the fact that the OP selected it).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$qResults  =  mysql_query("SELECT column1, column2 FROM tablename ORDER BY column1 ASC, column2 ASC");
```

Refer:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: This doesn't result in the order the OP is looking for. You should read the question again.